# How to use Str::words() safely for contents processed by WYSIWYG editor in Laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel-4

I am using wysiwyg editor to edit my contents in front end. So at the time of saving data in database the contents are saved in html structure format. At the content listing page I am stripping out the text for the option of read more using Str::words. It works fine when the contents are plain text, but how to deal with html contents? For example, if the content is this, and I am limiting 3 words:-

```
<b>This is a content of the blog</b>
```

So above function will clip out before closing the bold tag, effecting the entire html document. Any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want to use `strip_tags` on your content before Str::words. This will remove any HTML tags from you content.